# How to download file using primefaces and jsf?

Tags: database, image, jsf, primefaces, download

I am developing a jsf/primefaces web application which utilizes primefaces FileUpload and FileDownload. I am able to upload the image to the database as a blob. However i am unsure on how to retrieve it.[image]

The picture above shows the id of the images in a data table. And when the user clicks download the image corresponding to that id should download. However i am unsure on how to do this. Can anyone link me to a tutorial or give me some pointers on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution from the [jsf2-export-pdf-portlet](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-faces/tree/3.1.x/demos/bridge/jsf2-export-pdf-portlet) created by Neil Griffin. It shows you how to develop Jsf Resource and ResourceHandler. It gives you information about how the bridge uses `Resource_Phase` for generating Url.